# SQL query with multible table joins count and sum issue

Tags: sql, multiple-tables

There are 2 tables.  1 tblBidder and 1 tblItem.  They share 1 field that makes the association between the fields in each table.  It is the bidder_number (for tblBidder) and item_bidder_number (for tblItem).  Then, they have a corresponding field of bidder_sale_id (for tblBidder) and item_sale_id (for tblItem).  This field is for a group of items being sold all during 1 sitting.  So you could have 20 different items being sold individually, but they all have the same sale ID because they are being sold on the same day.

I am trying to pull a report of the total number of bidders per bidder type who were registered for auction 235, and also find out how much the total sale was that auction for that particular group.  Here is what I have for an SQL query:

```
SELECT     COUNT(dbo.tblBidder.bidder_type) AS TotalRegistrants, SUM(dbo.tblItem.item_premium + dbo.tblItem.item_pr) AS SumTotal, 
                  dbo.tblBidder.bidder_type
FROM         dbo.tblItem INNER JOIN
                  dbo.tblBidder ON dbo.tblItem.item_bidder_number = dbo.tblBidder.bidder_number     AND dbo.tblItem.item_sale_id = dbo.tblBidder.bidder_sale_id
WHERE     (dbo.tblItem.item_sale_id IN (235))
GROUP BY dbo.tblBidder.bidder_type
```

That query returned the incorrect number of registrants, but correct sum total:

```
TotalRegistrants        SumTotal            bidder_type

10          3760.0000       Absentee Bidder
133         173870.6250     Floor Bidder
77          81300.0000      Internet Bidder
29          34862.2500      Mail Bidder
100         242790.2500     Phone Bidder
```

This is just to get the total number of registrants:

```
SELECT     COUNT(bidder_type) AS TotalBidders, bidder_type
FROM         dbo.tblBidder
WHERE     (bidder_sale_id = 235)
GROUP BY bidder_type
```

Which returns correctly at:

```
TotalBidders    bidder_type

41      Absentee Bidder
79      Floor Bidder
60      Internet Bidder
35      Mail Bidder
82      Phone Bidder
```

If I try to join the items table to this last query, even if I don't select any new columns, the TotalBidders returns numbers in the thousands.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if you try this?:

```
SELECT  COUNT(DISTINCT dbo.tblBidder.bidder_id) AS TotalRegistrants, 
        SUM(dbo.tblItem.item_premium + dbo.tblItem.item_pr) AS SumTotal,
        dbo.tblBidder.bidder_type 
FROM dbo.tblBidder 
LEFT JOIN dbo.tblItem 
ON dbo.tblItem.item_bidder_number = dbo.tblBidder.bidder_number
AND dbo.tblItem.item_sale_id = dbo.tblBidder.bidder_sale_id 
WHERE (dbo.tblBidder.bidder_sale_id  = 235) 
GROUP BY dbo.tblBidder.bidder_type
```

Comment: Still the correct pricing, but wrong count, and different count than what I'm already getting and what it should be.

Comment: @James - Can you try now?. And tell me if the results of the count are greater or smaller. Thanks

Comment: The count for all of them is 1.

Comment: @James - Yeah, the column on the `COUNT(DISTINCT ` should've been the key of the table `dbo.tblBidder`, I changed now (but I'm not sure if its the right column, so you should change it to the primary key of the bidder table)